# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in Java from CSV file

Tags: java, arrays, methods

trying to read the inputs from the CSV file, but got this error. Can someone tell why?
trying to take three inputs from the user (name, id, GPA) all as a string (I know it is not a good practice)
[image: error message]

[image: input]

Comment: Looks like your file format is wrong. In some line of your files you don't have two commas so you get the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: Can you display an example of your input file?

Comment: can you post the content of you file

Comment: 1,sally,1                I'm displaying them in one column

Comment: can please check the question, i have edit it and added a picture for the input

Comment: don't share screenshot of your code.

Answer (score 0):

There is an inconsistency with your csv file that you are reading. Probably a missing `,` somewhere:

`12345,Molly,2.5
 54321,Sally 3.5`

Line 2 will cause an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: should they be added in one column or each value should be separated in columns

Comment: I'm not sure about excel, just copy the rows from your excel and paste it into a .txt file.. Rename that file's extension to .csv